# zsh: print time next to command on execute

Tags: zsh

I want to configure zsh to append the time each command started next to the line command was executed on. For example:

```
# before I press ENTER
$ ./script

# after I press enter
$ ./script [15:55:58]
Running script...
```

I came up with the following config (which also colors the timestamp yellow):

```
preexec () {
  TIME=`date +"[%H:%M:%S] "`
  echo -e "$1 %{$fg[yellow]%}\033[1A\033[1C${TIME}$reset_color"
}
```

But it breaks and prints `{` and `%` characters on basic commands such as `cat` and `echo`. It also breaks on password prompts (macOS terminal). For example with `echo`:

```
$ echo "hello" [15:55:58] 
hello"hello" %{%}
```

How can I fix this config?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inspired me and based on your script I wrote mine. I have tested this on zsh 5.4.smth.

```
preexec () {
  local TIME=`date +"[%H:%M:%S] "`
  local zero='%([BSUbfksu]|([FK]|){*})'
  local PROMPTLEN=${#${(S%%)PROMPT//$~zero/}}
  echo "\033[1A\033[$(($(echo -n $1 | wc -m)+$PROMPTLEN))C $fg[blue]${TIME}$reset_color"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.zshrc` file, put:

```
function preexec() {
  timer=${timer:-$SECONDS}
}

function precmd() {
  if [ $timer ]; then
    timer_show=$(($SECONDS - $timer))
    export RPROMPT="%F{cyan}${timer_show}s %F{$black%}"
    unset timer
  fi
}
```

And that should give you something like this:
[image]